# JQuery-mobile, left sidebar/toolbox

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, themes

I am having difficulties creating a side-bar toolbox on my jQuery-mobile app.

I want a render like this : http://www.paultrifa.com/envato/themeforest/side/red/preview/ with a fixed left navbar.
I saw in the document that the header and footer have native "fixed" feature, but can't find something out of box for my needs.

I have tested with the Grid system (one with fixed size in PIXEL - for the toolbox) and the other part (the content of the page) in responsive but it's very buggy !

And how do i have to structure my code? The best way will be to put the sidebar HTML code outside the page container, but i have some problems.

I tried with a basic CSS:

```
.sidebar{
    display:inline-block;
    width:47px;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    background-image:url(images/sidebar-bg.png);
}
```

It works but the content of the page is cropped. I have to re-size the width of the "page" container, but the size of my panel is in pixels, so there I have another problem...

If anyone has some tips, it will be great!

Edit :

Full code :

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">

    <!-- header -->
    <div data-role="header">

    </div> <!-- /header -->

    <!-- content -->
    <div data-role="content">

        <div class="ui-grid-b my-breakpoint">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <div class="sidebar">   
                    <!-- SIDEBAR CONTENT -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                {% block body %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- /content -->

    <!-- footer -->
    <div data-role="footer">

    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->
```

My problem here is that the toolbar is beetween the header and the footer...

Comment: What do you mean by OOB?

Comment: Have you tried using CSS calc?

Comment: OOB -> Out of Box, sorry

Comment: I made an update with full code but I really have to move the sidebar out of the content area, cause the grid thing is not usable, and there is some padding... And is not situable in the case if want to change the side (left/right) ine somes pages :S

But i have found no solution cause if i put it out the Content area, the bar will be in front of the content. If i do a margin of 47px for the content, it's ok but the content exceeds on the right !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/xTFRr/. Does that do what you want?

On pagebeforeshow, I size the content div to the height of the screen:

```
$('#page1').on("pagebeforeshow", function(e){
    var viewport_height = $(window).height();
    var content = $('#contentDiv');
    var content_height = viewport_height - 5;
    content_height -= (content.outerHeight() - content.height());
    content.height(content_height);
});
```

Within the page content, I have a sidebar div and mainCont div with the following CSS:

```
.sidebar{
display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0;
width:47px;
background-color:#C34848;   
}
.mainCont{
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    margin-left: 47px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 12px;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Absolute positioning is used to place the sidebar on the left, and then the mainCont div is absolutely positions with scrolling enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to not `float` this, but you should `absolutely position` it to the left. Then you need the make the rest of your page fill around it. Without more code, or a link, I can't give an example, but you should be able to catch my drift.

Comment: No I'd suggest the fluid layout using floats in such scenarios

Comment: IMHO, the fluid layout is great, but has an issue with the fact that rest of the content will be placed under the sidebar. I would position it left, and then use the fluid layout for the rest of the page.